# types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor (ExtJs 3.3)

Tags: extjs

I recently inherited a big ExtJs application and for the life of me I can't seem to find where my issue is. The error that FireBug is throwing is..

The error

> types[config.xtype || defaultType] is not a constructor

The code

> create : function(config, defaultType){
>        return config.render ? config : new typesconfig.xtype ||
>   defaultType; 
>   }

The above error is in ext-all-debug-w-comments.

A quick check of "defaultType" shows it to be "panel" and I know that "is not a constructor" errors are almost always indicative that something hasn't loaded yet. Problem is that I can't seem to solve this one.

I am assuming that Ext.Panel is the problem here but I was under the impression that it loaded with

```
<script src="/ext-3.3/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript">
```

that I have in the HEAD.

It would also be helpful if I knew what was calling the "create". I kid you not, this is one massive sized application.

The includes for ExtJs are below.... (they are in the BODY)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-3.3/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/ext/ux/Spinner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/ext/ux/form/SpinnerField.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/ext/layout/CardLayout-crossfade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/plugin/DragDropTabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/ext/ux/Lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/ext/ux/NoLayoutCollapsed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/ContractionsStore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/Render.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/selection/SelectionHelper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/core/StationsStore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/LeftColumn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/Config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/Container.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/TextColumn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/TextWx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/AbsWxAero.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/Metar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/MetarSettings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/TafSettings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/TextWxSettings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/Taf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/text/ForecastRegions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/Selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/Container.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/ChartTBarButton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/LegendPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/SingleSite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/AddsAirmetChart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/selection/Selector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/ChartCardPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/sponsored/content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/sponsored/SponsorPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/chart/charts-tree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/initStores.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/wx/init.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?
JW

Comment: OMG! including so much files? Why don't you switch to v4.2 ?

Comment: 1. I inherited this app, that would have to come later. 2. It all gets minified through Ant. Thanks for your concern. JW

Answer (score 3):

It means you're trying to create something via `xtype` but it can't find it in the registered list. Usually means either you've got a typo or the file isn't included. In the debugger, look at the locals/callstack, see what xtype it's attempting to create.